# Correctly mapping array element using the Knockout mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a viewModel that looks something like this when simplified:

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.selectedObject = ko.observable({});
  self.getUnit = function(){
    //get the selected object from the server side as json
    self.selectedObject(ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping));
  };
  self.addObjectMember = function(){
    self.selectedObject().objectMembers.push(new ObjectMemberViewModel(null, self.selectedObject()));
  self.save = function(){
    var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self.selectedObject);
    //ship data to server
  }
```

The data received from the server contains an array called `objectMembers` that has some properties inside it. The properties might differ between different objects.

My mapping object look like this:

```
var mapping = {
  'objectMembers': {
    create: function(options){
      return new ObjectMemberViewModel(options.data, options.parent);
    }
  }
};
```

To see my problem, I'll give an example:

The user loads the page, and then fetches an object. That object includes two elements inside the `objectMembers` array. Then those are mapped using the ko.mapping.fromJS and everything works just fine. I can modify my viewModel using my model and the viewModel is updated. Then the user clicks a button that triggers the `addObjectMember` function, adding a third entry to the observableArray. I can interact with this also, and any changes done to my model can be seen in the viewModel as expected.

The problem comes when I click save. If I debug the save method, and check the contents of self.selectedObject, I can see that it contains what I want it to, but the object that is mapped back into the variable `data` has the last element in the `objectsMembers` array as an empty object (`{}`). The two other object look as I want them to.

I think I know why. The two first object have their `__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties` containing all the properties they had when it got mapped initially. The last one however has an empty `__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties`, and therefore I guess that no properties are mapped back.

So I need to do one of these things I guess:

1. When adding the object to the array on `addObjectMember` I need to get the `__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties` set so that it gets mapped back when I save.
2. When mapping back, I include all the properties on the mapped object regardless of their presence inside the `__ko_mapping__.mappedProperties`.

I have no clue how to do any of them that does not feel like a dirty hack, so any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the `ko.toJS` will not care about what was mapped originally. Are there any problems combining it so that I use `ko.mapping.fromJS` to create the model, and then `ko.toJS` to make it back into javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `ko.toJS` instead of `ko.mapping.toJS`. `ko.toJS` does not care about `__ko_mapping__`, and maps everything (including `__ko_mapping__`).

That means it maps a bit more than I need, but other than that it works just fine.